# Conflict between marvosym and mathabx

Tags: incompatibility, mathabx

in this minimal example code, I want to use this commands: `\divides` from `mathabx` and `\MVAt` from `marvosym`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
$a\divides b$ and my e-mail es foo@foo.tex %\MVAt replace @.
\end{document}
```

This is one of my error's list

`Command \Sun already defined. \newcommand\Sun{\mvchr{192}}.

I have no idea how to fix it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both packages define macros for the astronomical symbols and some astrological ones:

```
\Sun \Moon \Mercury \Venus \Earth \Mars \Jupiter \Saturn \Uranus \Neptune \Pluto

\Gemini \Leo \Libra \Scorpio \Aries \Taurus
```

If you don't need them, the package loading order is irrelevant:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\let\Sun\relax
\let\Moon\relax
\let\Mercury\relax
\let\Venus\relax
\let\Earth\relax
\let\Mars\relax
\let\Jupiter\relax
\let\Saturn\relax
\let\Uranus\relax
\let\Neptune\relax
\let\Pluto\relax
\let\Gemini\relax
\let\Leo\relax
\let\Libra\relax
\let\Scorpio\relax
\let\Aries\relax
\let\Taurus\relax
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

$a\divides b$ and my e-mail es foo\MVat foo.tex

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will load those symbols from `marvosym`; switch the loading order for getting them from `mathabx`.

On the other hand, if you just need `\MVAt`, you can define it yourself without loading the whole `marvosym` package.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\newcommand{\MVAt}{{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}\symbol{`@}}}

\begin{document}

$a\divides b$ and my e-mail es foo\MVAt foo.tex

\end{document}
```

Comment: These examples code works fine and elegant :)